# bootstrap3-typeahead select first element with TAB

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-typeahead

The bootstrap3-typeahead has a function select, that selects the highlighted element in the dropdown.
What I want is instead of the highlighted element, the first element should be selected.
In the keyup function there is the case 9 for TAB.
I tried to set the first item as active, but this is wrong:

```
this.$menu.items[0].setAttribute('.active');
        var val = this.$element.find('.active').data('value');
        if (this.autoSelect || val) {
            this.$element
                  .val(this.updater(val))
                  .change();
        }
```

with this.prev() I can select the previos item, is there anything like this.first() ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. If anyone is interested:

```
this.$menu.find('li').first().data('value');
```

it finds the first item in the dropdown